# Vue3, getting state value from store to vue isn't working

Tags: vue.js, vuex

index.vue sends data to user.js and save on Array users, I checked users received the data from index.vue and it received by using localstorage.
And I tried to get Array users on chat.vue from users.js

However, getting Array users on chat.vue isn't wokring.
Here is my codes.

1. index.vue
   This code is working.

```
  methods: {
    onClickJoinBtn(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
     this.$store.dispatch('user/userJoin', {
        name: this.user.name,
        room: this.user.room
      });
      console.log("this.user.room:",this.user.room)
       this.$router.push(`/chat?channel=${this.user.room}`)
    }
  },
```

2. users.js

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
      user:{
        name:'',
        room:''
      },
      users: [],
      rooms: [],
      pulledUser:''
  },
  getters: {
    getCurrentUser(state,name) {
      return state.users.find(user => user.name == name);
    },
    getLeftUser(state) {
      return state.pulledUser;
    }
  },
  computed:{
      getRoomUsers(state,room) {
      return state.users.filter(user => user.room == room);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    putUser(state,user)
    {
      state.users.push({
        name:user.name,
        room:user.room
        });
      console.log("users array: ",state.users);    
      state.users.forEach(user => {//working 
        if(user.room=="Melo")
          console.log("filtered userName: ", user.name)
      });
    },
    pullUser(state,name){
      const index = state.users.find(user=>user.name===name)
      if (index !== -1) {
        state.pulledUser=state.users.splice(index, 1)[0];
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    userJoin(context,user) {
      console.log('...user: ',{...user})
      context.commit('putUser',user);
    },
    userLeave(context,{...user}){
      context.commit('pullUser',user);
    }
  }
}
```

3. chat.vue

```
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default {
  created() {
    this.channel = this.$route.query.channel || '';
    this.websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999/ws');
    this.websocket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log('open event..', event);
      
    };

    this.websocket.onerror = (event) => {
      console.log('error', event);
    };

    this.websocket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
      const vo = JSON.parse(data);
      if (vo.channel === this.channel) {
        this.appendNewMessage(this.$store.username, vo.message, vo.time);
      }
    };

     this.websocket.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log('close', event); 
    };

   
  },data() {
    return {
      user:{
        name:'',
        room:''
      },
      username: 'tempUser',
      websocket: null,
      channel: '',
      chatInputMessage: '',
    };
  },
  computed:{
    getThisRoom(){
      
    },
    userList(){
      //TODO this.$store.state.users can't get the users from ./store/user.js 
      console.log(this.$store.state.users);//undefined
      return this.$store.state.users;//
    },
    getUser(name){
      //TODO get the name from store
      let latestUser = this.$store.state.users.length -1 ;
      return this.$store.state.users[latestUser];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send() {
      if (this.chatInputMessage === '') return;
      const message = {
        channel: this.channel,
        message: this.chatInputMessage,
      };
      this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
      this.chatInputMessage = '';
    },
    onEnter() {
      this.send();
    },
    appendNewMessage(username, message, time) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('message');
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.classList.add('meta');
      p.innerText = username;
      p.innerHTML += `<span>${moment(time).format('h:mm a')}</span>`;
      div.appendChild(p);
      const para = document.createElement('p');
      para.classList.add('text');
      para.innerText = message;
      div.appendChild(para);
      document.querySelector('.chat-messages').appendChild(div);
    },
    onClickleaveRoom(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         this.$store.dispatch('user/userLeave',)
         this.$router.replace('/')
    }
   
  }
};
</script>
```

Below code is working I checked data has been received from index.vue and it has.

```
      console.log("users array: ",state.users);    
      state.users.forEach(user => {//working 
        if(user.room=="Melo")
          console.log("filtered userName: ", user.name)
      });
```

But, below userList isn't working, on console it shows this.$store.users is "undefined".

```
computed:{
 userList(){
      //TODO this.$store.state.state.users can't get the users from ./store/user.js 
      console.log(this.$store.state.users);//undefined
      return this.$store.state.users;
    },
```

index.js//create Store

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import movie from './movie.js'
import about from './about.js'
import user from './user.js'

export default createStore({//store생성
  modules:{
    movie: movie,
    about: about,
    user: user
  },
  plugins:[
    createPersistedState({
      paths:['user'],
    })
  ]
})
```

main.js // createApp

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routes/index.js'
import store from './store/index.js'
import loadImage from './plugins/loadImage.js'

// import io from 'socket.io-client';
// const socket = io('http://localohst:3000', {transport:['websocket']});



const app = createApp(App)

// app.config.globalProperties.$socket=socket;//socket 전역변수화

app.use(router)// $route, $router
  .use(store) // $store
  .use(loadImage) // $loadImage
  .mount('#app') //
```

Comment: I think you want `this.$store.state.users`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is below

```
this.$store.state.user.users
```